# python function, json.loads() : No JSON object could be decoded

Tags: python, json

The code is very simple:

```
import requests
import json

r = requests.get('https://www.baidu.com/')
r.encoding = 'utf-8'
json.loads(r.text,'utf-8')
```

I always recieve this error information:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#57>", line 1, in <module>
json.loads(r.text,'utf-8')
File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 352, in loads
return cls(encoding=encoding, **kw).decode(s)
File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 364, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Can anyone help me solving this problem? Thanks!

Comment: It is because the response sent from `baidu.com` is not JSON. Open `https://www.baidu.com/` in your browser see what you'll get.

Comment: Thanks, what I get from r.text is u'<html>\r\n<head>\r\n\t<script>\r\n\t\tlocation.replace(location.href.replac e("https://","http://"));\r\n\t</script>\r\n</head>\r\n<body>\r\n\t<noscript> <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=baidu.com/">; </noscript>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>'.  Do you know what's the problem?

Comment: What you get is something that can't be converted to JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will help you to figure out what's going on ;)

```
import requests
import json

r = requests.get('https://www.baidu.com/')
r.encoding = 'utf-8'

try:
    foo = json.loads(r.text, 'utf-8')
    print "Yay, I got a json from baidu!"
except Exception, e:
    print "Why didn't i get a json from baidu? Maybe it wasn't a json..."
    print "What is it then? It seems is a {0} whose length is {1}".format(
        r.text.__class__, len(r.text)
    )
```

Comment: I ran your code and get 'It seems is a <type 'unicode'> whose length is 227

Comment: r.text=    u'<html>\r\n<head>\r\n\t<script>\r\n\t\tlocation.replace(location.href.replac    e("https://","http://"));\r\n\t</script>\r\n</head>\r\n<body>\r\n\t<noscript>    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://www.baidu.com/">    </noscript>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>'

Comment: @Yuandong Exactly, that was my point, as you can see that's a string containing HTML code, which is not JSON. That's why you can't decode it, you need to make a request returning a JSON object instead.

Comment: Thank you so much, actually I have no idea of what's the difference between JSON and HTML, I just want to run a .py(provided by others) to extract data from website. The code here was copied from the original .py(different URL though), and it never works. Could you explain why it doesn't return JSON object?  And how can I make a request returning a JSOM object?

Comment: @Yuandong You're welcome, but you haven't marked the answer as accepted, anything else is still unclear to you?